# Terminate function call if it takes over 1 millisecond python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, timeout

I have a list of black-box functions (no critical data handling, no side-effects from calling, okay to terminate prematurely) which need to be executed and their return values aggregated:

```
aggregate = [result for fn in seq for result in fn()]
```

The functions generally return within a few microseconds, however there are edge cases which I cannot influence which cause some of them to occasionally raise exception, return invalid type (e.g. `None` instead of iterable), or hang indefinitely.

To handle invalid output and exceptions, I wrote a decorator:

```
def safe_call(fn, valid_type, default, error_handler=None):
    try:
        val = fn()
        if isinstance(val, valid_type):
            return val
        if error_handler is not None:
            error_handler(TypeError("Invalid return type"))
    except Exception as e:
        if error_handler is not None:
            error_handler(e)
    return default
```

Now the only problem are hangs. Entire expression above should **always** be evaluated within milliseconds, and to ensure that I'm trying to implement a 1ms timeout for each function in the sequence.

I tried threading and multiprocessing, but I cannot properly terminate problematic threads, and overhead of starting a new process is too high and by itself exceeds the timeout value of 1 millisecond.

I tried using signals, benchmark indicating a 25% overhead on each call which is acceptable, but the evaluation is being done from a django's view which doesn't run in main thread, so signals don't work properly.

My current workaround is to have a separate process for each function constantly synchronizing with its parent process through a Queue, waiting to be called. This way, the parent can trigger the call on demand, wait 1ms, then check if the result has been sent back - saving the result if it has, or terminating the process otherwise.

It does work as far as performance is concerned, but there is 1400-1700% memory overhead from this solution which is not acceptable.

So how do I timeout a function call with a <1 ms precision without a huge memory overhead?

Comment: There has to be a trade-off somewhere which it sounds like you've already realized.

Comment: @coldspeed I do not believe that my question is duplicate of the marked one. The marked question is asking about timing out a call with orders of magnitude of less precision. In my original post I mention all methods proposed as answers to that question, and they have failed me for reasons I described.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I can accept a trade-off, but all of these add a factor of 10x or greater to memory consumption or time required to execute. If overhead from timeout wrapper is so large that it triggers a timeout itself, there has to be room for improvement